# java.lang.NullPointerException in xml

Tags: java, android, xml, nullpointerexception

this code correctly work in MainActivity, but i am want to put some animation methods in different class, and call it from there, but i have got an error
i am trying to understand, why it shows me an error
any ideas?

```
public class AnimationClass extends MainActivity{
    private static ImageButton heart_icon,bee_icon;
    private static int kill_flag = 0;
    private static Animation anim_heart, anim_bee;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        heart_icon=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.heart_icon);
        bee_icon = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.bee_icon);
    }

    public static void loadAnimations(Activity activity){
        anim_heart = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.heart_anim);
        heart_icon.startAnimation(anim_heart);

        anim_bee = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.bee_anim);
        bee_icon.startAnimation(anim_bee);
    }
}
```

Animation:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:shareInterpolator="true">
    <scale
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="1.2"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.2"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"/>
    <rotate
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:duration="1200"
        android:fromDegrees="-20"
        android:toDegrees="15"
        android:pivotX="80%"
        android:pivotY="20%"/>
    <translate
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:duration="800"
        android:toXDelta="5"
        android:toYDelta="-5"/>
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0"
        android:toAlpha="1"
        android:duration="1500"/>

</set>
```

the error in:`anim_heart = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.heart_anim);`

Comment: Post the full error message.

Comment: Before you try to find view by id you have to set your layout : `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);`

Comment: @Josef thanks, but no, the problem was not here.
it looks like the correct answer was given by user3249477

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand how static variables and methods work.

When you create an object of `AnimationClass`:

```
new AnimationClass()
```

`onCreate` is called and the two `ImageButtons` are set properly.

However when you call the static method `loadAnimations`, the ImageButton variables might be still null, which in return will throw the NPE.

Different solutions:

1. Check for null variables:

   ```
   public static void loadAnimations(Activity activity){
       anim_heart = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.heart_anim);
       if (heart_icon != null) {
           heart_icon.startAnimation(anim_heart);
       }

       anim_bee = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.bee_anim);
       if (bee_icon != null) {
           bee_icon.startAnimation(anim_bee);
       }
   }
   ```
2. If the Activity you pass as an argument to `loadAnimations` contains the views in question, you may want to find them on the spot:

   ```
   public static void loadAnimations(Activity activity){
       heart_icon = (ImageButton) activity.findViewById(R.id.heart_icon);
       bee_icon = (ImageButton) activity.findViewById(R.id.bee_icon);

       anim_heart = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.heart_anim);
       heart_icon.startAnimation(anim_heart);

       anim_bee = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.bee_anim);
       bee_icon.startAnimation(anim_bee);
   }
   ```

Comment: all of this two var work, but:


1. in this case, animation does not start, becouse heart_icon is not null , if i understarnd it correctly...


2. in that case animation work good, but if i need to use heart_icon in this class but in different static void, i will be needet to repet this code again?
how to fix it and make easier?